# Modified Nuget package restore issue

Tags: visual-c++, tfs, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

We use [cpprestsdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn/) package in our project. You may notice below that **cppresdsdk.target** is configured only for **Debug** and **Release** configurations. But we have, respectively, **Debug_StaticLib** and **Release_StaticLib**. So we need to modify *.target file.

This is what we get from nuget.org:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release' And '$(Platform)' == 'x64' And '$(Disable-cpprestsdk-v140-windesktop-msvcstl-dyn-rt-dyn)' == ''">
  <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\native\v140\windesktop\msvcstl\dyn\rt-dyn\x64\Release\cpprest140_2_9.dll" />
  <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\native\v140\windesktop\msvcstl\dyn\rt-dyn\x64\Release\cpprest140_2_9.pdb" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This is what we need:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="$(Configuration.ToLower().Contains('release')) And '$(Platform)' == 'x64' And '$(Disable-cpprestsdk-v140-windesktop-msvcstl-dyn-rt-dyn)' == ''">
  <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\native\v140\windesktop\msvcstl\dyn\rt-dyn\x64\Release\cpprest140_2_9.dll" />
  <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\native\v140\windesktop\msvcstl\dyn\rt-dyn\x64\Release\cpprest140_2_9.pdb" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Ok, we put this modified under source control (**TFS**). But when someone tries to restore packages he gets an error that **cppresdsdk.target** is locked (read-only) by TFS. And we need to manually *check-out this file, restore package and undo pending changes*. That's weird.

My question is how we should handle such cases? Do we need to upload our own package with fixes, or we can somehow patch existing one? Or we can somehow fix this issue on our client side?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share the detailed error message, screenshot will be better? Are you able to check in the file cppresdsdk.target successfully? Can you see a Lock pending change for this file, and who lock this file?

Comment: Did you check-in the package in the packages directory of your solution? And are you using a server work space? In a server workspace all files are read only until you check them out. VS will checkout your source files for you etc. as soon as you start typing but I'm assuming  NuGet package restore doesn't work this way when it comes to the contents of the packages inside the packages folder. As a workaround you could switch to a local workspace, that will not mark your files as read-only. If you are using VSTS or TFS2015+ consider publishing your modified package to your own feed.